# Power BI Embedded: Use Hash Value in RLS?

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, ssas

All examples of Row Level Security in Power BI Embedded that I see on the internet are using Username() functions in RLS.

But I want to use a hash value to do RLS in my system. I want to create a role in my power bi report that compares a column value of a dimension to a Hash passed via iframe.

DimensionA:
[Column7] = 'hashValuePassedByIframe'

Is possible? There are articles/examples on the internet with this approach that I want? Or all RLS techniques of PowerBy are bound to User() functions?

Thank You

Comment: If it's ok for you to hide the filtering pane, then you can simply [filter](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Filters) the data.

Comment: Thank You, Andrey Nikolav. I think I will do this filter approach